# I updated Miktex today and then cannot compile

Tags: xetex, miktex-update

I updated Miktex today and then cannot compile.
My minimal tex code is:

(File name: try.tex)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

My compile code is:

```
latexmk.exe -xelatex try.tex
```

The Error says:

```
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 26 Dec. 2019, version: 4.67.
Latexmk: applying rule 'xelatex'...
Rule 'xelatex': The following rules & subrules became out-of-date:
      'xelatex'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'xelatex'
------------
------------
Running 'xelatex -no-pdf -recorder  "try.tex"'
------------
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (MiKTeX 2.9.7300 64-bit)

Sorry, but xelatex did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\xelatex.log
Latexmk: fls file doesn't appear to have been made.
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  xelatex: Command for 'xelatex' gave return code 1
      Refer to 'try.log' for details
----------------------
This message may duplicate earlier message.
Latexmk: Failure in processing file 'try.tex':
   (Pdf)LaTeX didn't generate the expected log file 'try.log'
----------------------
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs, or warnings treated as errors.
```

upd: An issue has been submitted to Miktex team, url: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/474

Comment: The standard question for miktex is how exactly did you update? Miktex user mode plus miktex admin mode. Also remember to manually update the package repo list (it's in one of the menus as miktex apparently does not automatically do it). Also it is useful to seethe full log of your compilation  not that xelatex.log

Comment: Don't run latexmk or any such tool when you get such an error. Run xelatex directly to get a better error message.

Comment: xelatex works fine for me after todays update of miktex.

Comment: @daleif "mpm --update". I install miktex only for myself, and therefore all in user mode. I don't know how to read the log.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer "xelatex try.tex" gives the same error code. So maybe I should reinstall miktex?

Comment: @daleif UPD: I reinstalled miktex and the problem went.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer UPD: I reinstalled miktex and the problem went.